# Remove first comma in string TSQL

Tags: t-sql, azure-synapse

I am trying to prune tags if 'وسم' is mentioned, but when doing so, the first comma still remains.

```
--drop tags like 'وسم' 
drop table temp
CREATE TABLE temp (tags NVARCHAR(1500));
INSERT INTO temp values(N'تفاحة, أناناس, وسم')
INSERT INTO temp values(N'تفاحة, موز, برتقال, وسم, العنب')
```

I tried running this:

```
    set temp.tags = replace(tags,N'وسم,','')
    where tags like N'%وسم%'
    update temp
    set temp.tags = replace(tags,N'وسم','')
    where tags like N'%وسم%'
```

and this was the output:

```
تفاحة, أناناس,
تفاحة, موز, برتقال, العنب
```

what it should be ideally:

```
تفاحة, أناناس
تفاحة, موز, برتقال, العنب
```

What i have also tried running was:

```
UPDATE temp
SET temp.tags =  case when charindex(',',temp.tags,0) =1 then right(temp.tags, len(temp.tags)-1) else temp.tags end
```

I ended up getting the same output where there is comma in the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you have a space between وسم and ,

You may want to consider replacing all of the following

```
update temp 
set temp.tags = replace(tags,N'وسم,','');

update temp 
set temp.tags = replace(tags,N',وسم','');

update temp 
set temp.tags = replace(tags,N', وسم','');

update temp 
set temp.tags = replace(tags,N'وسم ,','');
```

Comment: What if i addressed the spacing issue and then replaced the tags?

what I ran:
...
    update temp
    set temp.tags = replace(tags,' ','')
    where tags like N' '
...
tags after:
تفاحة, موز, برتقال, وسم, العنب
تفاحة, أناناس, وسم

Comment: my apologies, i deleted the earlier message. i did try using replace function, here is what i ran

...
    update temp
    set temp.tags = replace(tags,N'وسم,','')
    where tags like N'%وسم,%'

    update temp
    set temp.tags = replace(tags,N',وسم','')
    where tags like N'%,وسم%'
...
but 'وسم' still remained:
تفاحة, أناناس, وسم
تفاحة, موز, برتقال, وسم, العنب

Comment: That fine! I deleted mine too because in hindsight removing spaces isn't a great idea since you may want spaces if you're using different character sets/languages. I would just go with what I have updated my answer with above